# How to get http requests made by a QWebEngineView?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6, qtwebengine

I want to save to a file all the `http` requests (`get`, `post`, ...) that a `QWebEngineView` sends during a navigation session (like I would do with Firefox: `inspect > network > save to HAR file`).
Below are two codes I tried. In theses scripts I simply try to print the requests.

The first script displays correctly the view but fails to intercept the requests.

```
# SCRIPT 1

import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info: QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo):
        print()
        print("interceptRequest")
        print(info.requestUrl())
        print(info.requestMethod())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
        self.profile.setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
        print(self.profile)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView(self.profile, parent=self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://google.com"))
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

The second script catches and display the requests but the window is not rendered.

```
# SCRIPT 2

import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info: QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo):
        print()
        print("interceptRequest")
        print(info.requestUrl())
        print(info.requestMethod())


class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame):
        print("acceptNavigationRequest")
        print(url)
        return QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = QWebEngineView()
    interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
    profile = QWebEngineProfile()
    profile.setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
    page = MyWebEnginePage(profile)
    page.setUrl(QUrl("https://google.com"))
    browser.setPage(page)
    browser.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

Can somebody help patching either of these scripts?

Comment: Change to `self.interceptor` in the first example.

Comment: @musicamante: thanks! Now I would like to get the `request payload`. Not sure the interceptor can give it. Any clue?

Comment: @zigma12 Use [QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineurlschemehandler.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro I quote the doc. "A QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler can be registered for a profile by installUrlSchemeHandler() to add support for custom URL schemes." So, how should I use it as the scheme of all the requests I'm interested in is 'https' ? If I try, i get this warning: QWebEngineUrlScheme::registerScheme: Scheme "https" is a standard scheme

Comment: @zigma12 Redirect to a custom scheme, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60591722/984421). Obviously that implies you have to provide *all* the requested data yourself. Normally, chrome would handle everything internally via its own network stack, but there's no way to hook into that from Qt - you just have to wait until the content is delivered to the web-page. Of course, you can always use the chrome developer tools to inspect network traffic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892608/984421) for how to access them from Qt.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you. I'll give it a try. In the meantime, I've chose another way: selenium-wire that works pretty well, even though it adds extra dependencies to my project